# Pass parameter to function via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, system.reflection

I have an extesion method with the following signature

```
public static void AddConfiguration<TEntity>(this ModelBuilder builder, EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> configuration)
    where TEntity : class
{
    ...
}
```

I want to pass the parameter via Reflection and tried this method:

```
var ctors = type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public);
modelBuilder.AddConfiguration(ctors[0].Invoke(new object[] { }));
```

And this way:

```
modelBuilder.AddConfiguration(Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```

The classes I'm getting from reflection are like these:

```
public class LessonMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Lesson> 
public class ChapterMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Chapter> 
public class TrainingMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Training>
```

Both return an `object` so the method does not accept them. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You have to cast the result of `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Yes, but I'm getting the type via Reflection and it has that generic `TEntity` so I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Is the created object a `TEntity`?

Comment: @InBetween I updated the question with this information

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't see how this question is duplicated to the one you marked, except for the title. The problem is entirely different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Activator` has a generic method for creating typed instances that have a default constructor. By the looks of it you have that, so use the following:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<LessonMapping>();
modelBuilder.AddConfiguration(obj);
```

If that doesn't work for you or you need to pass arguments to your constructors:

```
var obj = (LessonMapping)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(LessonMapping));
modelBuilder.AddConfiguration(obj);
```

Finally if you are putting this code inside another generic method you would replace LessonMapping etc with a generic:

```
void DoSomethingGeneric<TEntity>(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>>();
    modelBuilder.AddConfiguration(obj);
}
```

**EDIT** add reflection of AddConfiguration method

For a non-generic usage of your AddConfiguration method you will have to use reflection to invoke it:

```
void DoSomethingNonGeneric(ModelBuilder builder, Type entityType)
{
    // make the generic type for the given entity type using the generic definition
    var entityConfigType = typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { entityType });

    // instantiate the entity type configuration
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(entityConfigType);

    // get and make a generic method to invoke with the object above. Check the binding flags if it doesn't find the method
    var methodDef = typeof(Extensions).GetMethod("AddConfiguration", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    var method = methodDef.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { entityConfigType });

    // and finally the end goal
    method.Invoke(null, new object[] { builder, obj });
}
```

My assumptions at this point are:

1. That you want to pass the type of the entities (as opposed to the configuration). If you are passing the type of the configuration classes then change the parameter name `entityType` to `entityConfigType` and remove the first line which makes the generic type. See below for type checking code that should replace that first line.
2. That your extension method is in a class called `Extensions`.
3. That you are checking the type conforms to the requirements of `AddConfiguration(...)` so you don't get invocation exceptions due to bad types being used. Again see below for an example of the type check I would typically add to such a non-generic method.
4. That the line which sets `methodDef` works as expected because I don't have means to test it at the moment.

If you are passing the `entityConfigType` directly and want to check the type then add this in the first few lines:

```
if (!CheckDerivesFrom(typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>), entityConfigType)
    throw new ArgumentException("entityConfigType");
```

And create the check method somewhere. I'm sure there must be an easier way to test if a type derives from a given generic definition but I use this all the time until I get shown the easier way.

```
bool CheckDerivesFrom(Type baseType, Type typeToCheck)
{
    if (!baseType.IsGenericDefinition)
        return baseType.IsAssignableFrom(typeToCheck);

    // assume typeToCheck is never a generic definition
    while (typeToCheck != null && typeToCheck != typeof(object))
    {
        if (typeToCheck.IsGenericType && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(typeToCheck.GetGenericDefinition()))
            return true;
        typeToCheck = typeToCheck.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting them via reflection because I have 50 mapping classes and it doesn't feel right to manually keep the `AddConfiguration` code synchronized, that's why I tried to do it via reflection. Your solution would work, but then I would have to manually cast the object to the type, so I would end up with 50 calls the same way. Now I see thatI should have put this context in the question to better describe the real problem..

Comment: Ok, then what you really want is to execute the configuration method by reflection also, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you, didn't work, I want to pass the configuration, so I made the changes you pointed and I'm getting the following error on the `Invoke` call: `'SORTE.Persistence.Mappings.ChapterMapping' cannot be converted to type 'SORTE.Persistence.EntityTypeConfiguration`1`, but the idea of calling the method itself with reflection is great. I'll try to go from here